# Cant start User Profile Sync Service

Tags: user-profile-service

**I have tested below condition and everything in right place but still I am not able to start the services**

1. You must run the UPA Service Instance as the Farm Account.
2. Farm Account must be a local administrator of the machine running the UPA
   Service Instance during provisioning only.
3. Farm Account must have Log on Locally rights.
4. The Synchronization Connection Account must have Replicating Directory Changes..
5. Sharepoint webservices application pool  started  in IIS.

**During the start process it get this error.**

```
UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Begin setup for 'Hamra User Profile Service'.
ILM Configuration: Configuring database
UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Failed to configure MIIS post database, will attempt during next rerun. Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Synchronization.ILMPostSetupConfiguration.ConfigureMiisStage2()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SetupSynchronizationService(ProfileSynchronizationServiceInstance profileSyncInstance).
UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: End setup for 'Hamra User Profile Service'.
```

**After it fails i get this error**

```
User Profile Application: SynchronizeMIIS encounters an exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.<>c__DisplayClass2.<IsTimerJobRunning>b__1()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob.IsTimerJobRunning(UserProfileApplicationJob timerJob)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ILMProfileSynchronizationJob.Execute()
```

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or 2013? How many servers in the farm? Have you inspected all of the servers and ensured that there are no other instances of UPSS running (or stuck on starting)?

Comment: SP 2013 with a WFE, APP (has the UPS), Search

Comment: I have made sure all instances of UPS have been deleted and recreated.  Same with Pools

Answer (score 1):

If it is still not provisioning even after a reboot, I'd delete the UPS App and start over from a clean configuration. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx